# How to get PathFigureCollection bounding rectangle

Tags: wpf, path, bounding-box

Is it possible to find the bounding rectangle of a PathFigureCollection object, in c# ?
(I know how to get it using a FrameworkElement but that's not what I want)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to include your `PathFigureCollection` in a `PathGeometry` object, and then you can access the bounding rectangle via the `Bounds` property.

**Example**

```
var geometry = new PathGeometry {
    Figures = new PathFigureCollection()
};
var boundingRect = geometry.Bounds;
```

Comment: +1, but of course you will have to assign the existing `PathFigureCollection` to the `Figures` property, not a new one. There is also a constructor that takes a `PathFigureCollection` parameter, so that you could simply write `var bounds = new PathGeometry(figures).Bounds;`